# Knockout.js: Null value in viewModel throws exception on foreach in view

Tags: view, knockout.js, viewmodel, nullreferenceexception

So I have a viewModel that looks like this

```
self.zones = ko.observableArray(zones);

   ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.zones(), function (zone) {


        //Get all rooms for the zone
        zone.rooms = getChildren("Organization", "Organization", zone.ID);


        if (zone.rooms.length > 0) {

            zone.buttons = ko.observableArray([]);

            //For each Room in Zone find the Buttons and add them to the Zone.buttons ObservableArray 
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(zone.rooms, function (room) {
                room.buttons = getChildren("Organization", "ButtonAssign", room.ID, { scheduleID: self.scheduleID });

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(room.buttons, function (button) {
                                           zone.buttons.push(button);
                });
            });

        }
```

So a you can see a zone has a property called buttons that is an Observable array

In my view I loop through each zone and output the buttons but one of my zones does not contain any buttons and throws this exception:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: buttons is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach:buttons

```
       <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: zones" style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <div class="zoneDiv">
                        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
                        <div data-bind="foreach:buttons" class="buttonsList">
                            <div class="buttonField">
                            <div data-bind="text: Name" style="float: left; width: 140px;">
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ID" />


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So my question is: How do you check for null values in an observable array before you start looping on it?

Additionally how do you check for a null value on a single property such as button.Name so that if the button has a name Ill write it out in a div and if it does not I wont write out anything (Or a default text).

So basically null checks on viewmodel properties in the view so I wont get this exceptions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: How do you check for null values in an observable
>   array before you start looping on it?

Use the `if` binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

But in the case of your code, why don't you just set an empty observableArray, that way you don't need to introduce any conditionals:

```
self.zones = ko.observableArray(zones);

ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.zones(), function (zone) {

    zone.rooms = getChildren("Organization", "Organization", zone.ID);
    zone.buttons = ko.observableArray([]);

    if (zone.rooms.length > 0) {

        //For each Room in Zone find the Buttons and add them to the Zone.buttons ObservableArray 
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(zone.rooms, function (room) {
            room.buttons = getChildren("Organization", "ButtonAssign", room.ID, { scheduleID: self.scheduleID });

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(room.buttons, function (button) {
                zone.buttons.push(button);
            });
        });

    }
});
```